# How to use NMEA time as elapsed time in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, stopwatch, nmea

In my windows form application I use `stopwatch` to calculate elapsed time between events but I want to get time from NMEA(GPRMC sentence) and want to use it as elapsed time. How can I do this?

Here is my code;

```
 Stopwatch watch=new Stopwatch();
    Textbox1.Text=gsaat.Substring(4,2);
    //gsaat is the UTC time part of the GPRMC;
     private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
     if ((Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) >= Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text) && Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text) >= Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)))
                        {
                             watch.Start();
                             var time = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    //I want to use gsaat as elapsed time in here instead of stopwatch
  label2.Text = String.Format("{0:00.00}", time);
    }
    }
```

EDIT;

In my application I am making a acceleration test by using GNSS module. In application I am setting a boundary conditions for velocity `Textbox1` and `Textbox2` and `label1` represents current velocity of the car and `label2` represents elapsed time when car's current velocity enter these boundaries .For example; I set `Textbox1.text=10` and `Textbox2.text=100` and car started to accelerate and I want to measure time difference between car is accclerating from 10 to 100. To do this I used `stopwatch` but I faced some problems. Now I want to use UTC time to measure time between car's velocity is 10 and 100. I can get UTC time from sentences of the GPRMC and I parsed it too.However I can't make start it from zero when car's velocity is 10 and stopped it when car velocity passed 100.

Comment: Your previous question was put on hold and it was suggested that you **edit** it to make it more clear. So, why have you instead opened a new question?

Comment: In previous question I asked to difference about counting time. In here I am asking to use NMEA sentence as a stopwatch.I think they are the different cases.

Comment: So basically it about how to parse NMEA time and compare to C# DateTime?

Comment: I parsed NMEA time from the sentence but I can not make it as a stopwatch.

Comment: Elapsed time since when? To get a lapse of time you need an initial date and the current date.

Comment: I don´t understand "as a stopwatch". The time transmitted is a absolute time. With a stopwatch you are able to take the time something needs. So what do you want to do exactly? Please explain in detail!

Comment: If you want to display the elapsed time since the time in the packet you have to parse it and subtract it from DateTime.UtcNow. The result is the elapsed time since then.

Comment: @Fildor: In fact you can get the GPS time, but it is not a NMEA packet. Moreover it is not the exact time because there are "errors" in the GPS time (AFAIK no switching seconds are applied to it).

Comment: @TomSchardt That's what I meant. You cannot "request" a specific NMEA packet. But anyway I am still confused about what OP actually wants to do.

Comment: @Fildor: I agree in every point :)

Comment: @Quanthema: Did you know you can change the default names of controls?

Comment: @TomSchardt Yes I know :)

Comment: @Quanthema: So you want to get the difference between two parsed timestamps? I still don´t get it :)   Realize you can´t use any timers in your app to measure the times because it takes time to transmit the packets, etc. If you have a packet close to velocity 10 and a packet close to velocity 100 just subtract the two timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear what you want to achieve, but a guess:

Parse the NMEA time and save it as DateTime object. Then do

```
var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - nmeaTimestamp;
```

to get the time since the transmitted timestamp.

Have a look at [NMEA documentation](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#rmc) for the meaning of this timestamp: UTC of position fix: It is the time when the transmitting station was close to the transmitted position.

If you want to be alarmed after a particular timespan use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). It will raise an event when the time has elapsed.

EDIT: Pick a packet close to velocity 10 and a packet close to velocity 100, parse the timestamps and subtract them:

```
var accelerationTimeMilliseconds = (timestampAt100 - timestampAt10).ElapsedMilliseconds;
```